# How to get the value of the input element of live of Value

Tags: jquery, ajax

HI,

```
 i am having a Input hidden element like
```

in my JQuery i am setting the value for the above input type after some ajax call
like

EDIT:::

```
                      $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
          url: "http://localhost/FormBuilder/index.php/forms/saveForm/",
                       async: false,
        data: "formname="+formname+"&status="+status,
                                                         success: function(msg){$("#FormID").val(msg); }//success

                 });//ajax
```

Now somewhere in the code after this i want to fetch the value of this FIeld.How to get this value on live of value for this input type..

EDIT:::
i am retriving like by var FORMID=$("#FormID").val();//but shows null

How to get the value of it on live of this Input element

Comment: do you mean you need to get the current value?? You might need some kind of timer or event like OnKeyUp to sense it live

Comment: i am setting its value inside the success function of an ajax call
see my edit please

Comment: Ya i need to get the current value of it after settings its value inside Ajax success

Answer (score 0):

To get a value, you just have to call the [val function](http://docs.jquery.com/Attributes/val) without arguments:

```
var value = $("#FormID").val();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try 
var FORMID=$("#FormID").val()

Answer (score 0):

as per @CMS described i write the complete code below

```
$.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "http://localhost/FormBuilder/index.php/forms/saveForm/",
        async: false,
        data: ({ formname:formname,status:status }),
        success: function(){
            var value = $("input[type=hidden][name=xxx]").val();
        }
})
```